# How is char array an oversize when filled by cin.get(a, size)

Tags: c++, arrays

```
char a[3];
cin.get(a, 10);
cout << a << endl;
```

- input: `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
- output: expected: `xx`; received: `xxxxxxx` <- length 10

The problem is how is it works with by a fixed size array but cout "exceeded length content" in it.

The output behavior is not undefined, but exactly length 10 on my machine.

Comment: `char a[3];` is a fixed size array!

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking (and I voted to close), but there's a chance that you *think* that operations know about the length of the array. they don't. the reason you have to provide the length explicitly is that they don't.

Answer (score 4):

Function `cin.get` receives a pointer to store data. If the memory pointed by this char array is not big enough to accommodate the data read, the behaviour of function execution is undefined.

It may output xx or yy or xxxxxxx. You should not question why, how etc as it is undefined.

When calling `cin.get(c_type_str, len)`, it is caller's responsibility to make sure that c_type_str is writable to atleast len bytes.

Buffer overrun(or bufferoflow) is an undefined behavior. There is no simple way to recognize bufferflow in c string (character array that should be appended by a null character) except to believe the length passed by caller is correct. And thus the function did it silently (+ you were lucky nothing bad happened) instead of throwing some exception or something similar.

And an undefined behavior is undefined behavior, best way to understand your output is to stop doing it. (Buffer overrun)

Using a `std::string` instead of `char array` to read input can help you here. `std::string` is flexible length and would throw `std::bad_alloc` exception in case there is a threat of reading extremely large input instead of doing something that is undefined.

**EDIT**
About your next question in edit section

> the problem is how is it works with by a fixed size array but cout
>   "exceeded length content" in it.

`char arrays` are special in C++ to maintain reverse compatibility with `c strings`. When you print a `c string`(character array terminated by a null character) using `std::cout`, it would keep printing characters as long as it doesn't encounter `NUL` character(`\0`). `std::cout` for the same reason won't honor the actual size of array.

The extra character you are seeing would be lying in contiguous section of memory after array end. It may be unclaimed yet or might be in use by some other user defined variable, some inbuild variable, other thread etc.

Comment: thx for your sharing, but i just wondering how it works like that. the result is not "undefined" as you mentioned. it outputs length 10 exactly..

Comment: I added more details as per your edited question.

Comment: i dont think cin has any overloaded function for string variable :)

Comment: [Operator >>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/) and [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) can be used to read a word or a line from `istream` (so `cin` can be used).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe i'm wrong, but when you create a variable you're holding a memory space for that variable. If you fill with more that can hold then you're using a memory space reserved to other variables or maybe other programs, and that's dangerous.
Char array must have an end character (NULL), to tell the compiler that's the end of varible, if you fill that NULL character with other, then the compiler continues reading the other variables space.

For example:

You have two variables in memory. VAR A and next to VAR A, VAR B.

**VAR A**    **VAR B**
 AAA0     BBB0

Program reads VAR A and gets **AAA0**, but if you fill VAR A with **AAAA** then:

**VAR A**    **VAR B**
 AAAA     BBB0

then program reads VAR A and gets **AAAABBB0**.

If you fill VAR A with **AAAAAA** then would be:

**VAR A**    **VAR B**
 AAAA     AAB0

You´re overwriting the other variable and program reads **AAAAAAB0**

That's what i've understood about variables. Maybe i'm wrong and someone knows better.